# MVVM & Serialization - How do I access the instances of classes?

Tags: c#, serialization, mvvm

I'm trying to learn how to serialize objects using the MVVM pattern. I have a `MainViewModel` which I would like to serialize. The serializer needs an instance of `MainViewModel` which should be created in my `MainView`, but I can't figure out how to access it. What are my options here? What would be the best route for me to take to manage to serialize my ViewModels (or Models for that matter)? Would making classes `static` help or would that just break the pattern (From what I've seen MVVM doesn't seem to be too big on `static`?

I am an inexperienced programmer (especially when it comes to MVVM), but I really am trying here I'm just at a loss at this point. I would really appreciate any help anybody could give me in figuring out how to serialize my ViewModels and Models.

```
"<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
 </Window.DataContext>
```

EDIT: More code

```
    private void SaveGameExecute()
    {
        ObjectSerializer<MainViewModel> objSerializer = new ObjectSerializer<MainViewModel>();
        objSerializer.SaveSerializedObject(this, "Save.sav");
    }

    private void LoadGameExecute()
    {
        ObjectSerializer<MainViewModel> objSerializer = new ObjectSerializer<MainViewModel>();
        /*****/ = objSerializer.GetSerializedObject("Save.sav");
    }
```

EDIT: Regardless of what it is I need to serialize, can anybody please give me some advice on how to do this using MVVM? If it's models I need to serialize, I still don't know how to access the particular instances of them. If anybody who has experience with serializing MVVM projects, please give me some guidelines of what to do. Without knowing how to locate the instances of the models/viewmodels/etc I don't really know what to do.

Comment: Where is your serialization logic called from? that should probably be in the ViewModels themselves, where you can just `this` to grab the current instance.

Comment: It's currently in a dedicated class. I'll try changing that.

Comment: yeah, but I mean, some action (from the user or otherwise) initiates the process. That action should be probably a `Command` or something in the ViewModel level, right?

Comment: What is your goal here? I am not sure why you would want to serialize a view model.

Comment: Eventually this will be a text-based game. I will need to be able to save all data relevant to the game and reload it. I should have made that more clear.

Comment: If I'm just serializing the models, what would be the ideal location for the serialization logic?

Comment: @HighCore I tried grabbing the instance via 'this' but I'm not able to; the compiler says "Cannot assign to '<this>' because it is read-only".

Comment: @dennisE you cannot assign to `this`, however you can PASS `this` to some other method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend that you rethink your need to serialize the ViewModel in the first place.

Typically you want to serialize the underlying Model.  The ViewModel is just an intermediary, to present the Model data in a way that the View can understand.  If your ViewModel contains data which you want to serialize and pass around, you might consider pushing it down, into the Model instead.

For serialization techniques in general, there are many.  Refer to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms233843.aspx) (there are walkthroughs at the bottom).

Comment: So in this scenario (just serializing the models) where should the serialization logic be?

Comment: See my edits.  Serialization in C# is very well-documented, and easily searched.

Comment: I think the serialization logic for serializing the model should be in the viewmodel, as it probably knows *when* the serialization should take place (e.g. user closed the view or triggered a "save" command).

Comment: Or you could put it in a repository class to make it easier to serialize to a different medium

Comment: If I put it in a repository class wouldn't I still have the same issue of not being able to locate the instance of the class?

Comment: i agree with you @BTownTKD, but sometimes you want to serialize your view models if they container information specific to the view, to keep the view state for example between application runs. on the other hand Deenis E, just pass the object which handles serialization to your main window view model via the constructor and use it when the user clicks save for instance.