# Having lots of trouble with serialization in MVVM

Tags: c#, serialization, mvvm

I am working on a text-based game in WPF and I'm exploring MVVM. Currently I have 2 models in my project, Adventurer and GameDate (I am not concerned at this point with what should or should not be a model. I'll tackle that later). I have a viewmodel `MainViewModel` and a view `MainView`. `MainView` has buttons bound to save/load commands... And that's sort of where I'm stuck. I would very much like to implement a form of binary serialization; I have a class `ObjectSerializer` that functions and the appropriate parts of which are in the Save and Load commands in `MainViewModel`, but I don't know how to 'obtain' access to the instances of the classes that need to be serialized (in this case the models) since I never manually instantiated any of them. Furthermore, I would like to find a way to serialize them all in one file (a typical 'save' file for a game).

Would anybody who has dealt with serialization in MVVM please be kind enough to guide me through this process? I've been stuck on this all day while making no progress and it's driving me crazy. If somebody can provide some sort of example I will be forever in your debt. Thank you in advance; an answer that would get me over this hump will not go unappreciated. I really am trying here...

ObjectSerializer.cs

```
    protected IFormatter iformatter;

    public ObjectSerializer()
    {
        this.iformatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    }

    public T GetSerializedObject(string filename)
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            Stream inStream = new FileStream(
                filename,
                FileMode.Open,
                FileAccess.Read,
                FileShare.Read);
            T obj = (T)this.iformatter.Deserialize(inStream);
            inStream.Close();
            return obj;
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    public void SaveSerializedObject(T obj, string filename)
    {
        Stream outStream = new FileStream(
            filename,
            FileMode.Create,
            FileAccess.Write,
            FileShare.None);
        this.iformatter.Serialize(outStream, obj);
        outStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the role of a ViewModel in the MVVM pattern. The ViewModel is the model of the view -- it should have nothing to do with what you would be serializing and deserializing into and out of your persistent store. That would be the role of the Model in the MVVM pattern. I fear that you need to concern yourself with the difference right now, before you go any further, or you'll face more pain down the line.

Comment: What does your ObjectSerializer class look like?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that I worded that poorly. I understand that the model is what I need to be worried about as far as serialization goes. I was just saying that the save/load commands are in the ViewModel. I'll also edit my post and include the ObjectSerializer class.

Comment: I also noticed that you posted an almost identical question here 4 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844127/mvvm-serialization-how-do-i-access-the-instances-of-classes?rq=1 Please try to avoid simply rewording and reposting your questions in multiple places on StackOverflow, as it spreads out responses in multiple places, when they could all be contained in one place and make the relevant information easier to find.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When dealing with MVVM, your Models(M) are going to be encapsulated in your ViewModel(VM) and exposed to the View(V) only through the methods and properties that you explicitly expose on your ViewModel.  Your ViewModel will function mainly as an adapter between your Model(s) and you View.  All of your logic interacting with your application layer, such as any of the serialization you might need, will also be housed within the ViewModel and separated from any code that is UI specific.  This makes it easier to test your core application code without getting bogged down in things that you don't necessarily care about, such as if something is displayed in a `TextBox` or a `Label`.  This is much more preferable over having something like object serialization happening in your `xaml.cs` file.

**For Example:**

Consider that your `Adventurer` class looks something like this:

```
public class Adventurer { 
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Rank { get; set; } //Knight, Warlock, Whatever
}
```

Your `MainViewModel` might look something like this:

(Don't worry about `ViewModelBase`, just assume that for the purposes of this example it houses some code which allows your `MainViewModel` to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, a requirement for getting it to play nice with WPF's binding subsystem)

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    // When the ViewModel is created, populate _selectedAdventurer
    // with an empty Adventurer so that your form has something to  
    // bind to (and it can also be used as a "New" adventurer)
    private Adventurer _selectedAdventurer = new Adventurer();

    public string FirstName {
        get {
            return _selectedAdventurer.FirstName;
        }
        set {
            _selectedAdventurer.FirstName = value;
            // The following is implemented in our fictional
            // ViewModelBase, and essentially raises a notification
            // event to WPF letting it know that FirstName has changed
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    /*
       The remaining properties are implemented in a similar fashion, and in 
       this simple case are mainly acting as passthroughs to the view plus 
       a little bit of binding code
    */

    // These methods will house your save/load logic. I will assume
    // for simplicity that you already know how to wrap this logic in a
    // Command that can be bound to the view
    public void SaveAdventurer() {
       if(_selectedAdventurer != null) {
           SerializeToFile(_selectedAdventurer);
       }
    }

    public void LoadAdventurer() {
       _selectedAdventurer = LoadFromFile();
    }

    private void SerializeToFile(Adventurer adventurer) {
       // Use your serializer and save to file
    }

    private Adventurer LoadFromFile() {
       // Load from file and deserialize into Adventurer
    }

}
```

Now that you have a basic ViewModel wrapping your Model, you can easily bind UI controls to the properties on your VM once it is set as the `DataContext` for your view.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding LastName}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Rank}" />
<Button Value="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
<Button Value="Load" Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" />
```

Since you've set up your ViewModel to wrap your Model, and have properly bound the ViewModel properties to your View, when a user enters values into the textbox bound to `FirstName`, the value in `_selectedAdventurer.FirstName` will be directly updated with that input.  Essentially, the state of your underlying model will always be in sync with the values displayed in the UI.  Then when a user clicks the button labeled `Save`, your `SaveCommand` will execute and that will fire the code serialize the underlying `Adventurer` into a file, or database, or whatever.

This of course is a very simple example and functions mostly as a data entry form, but hopefully it will help you grasp the concept.  In order to better encapsulate the `Adventurer` binding logic, you may choose to create a child `AdventurerViewModel` that will be exposed to the View, rather than putting the properties directly on `MainViewModel`.  Perhaps you will want to add a property `IEnumerable<SaveGameFile> SavegameFiles` which you could bind to a `DropDownList`, and allow users to select which file they want to load.

Comment: This looks very promising. I have to leave the house for now but I'll play around with this when I get back. And thanks for such a great reply!

Comment: This works. I'm going to play around now and try to make the methods generic for re-useability.